# Sklearn regression input "Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2"

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I'm trying to parse this file http://www4.stat.ncsu.edu/~boos/var.select/diabetes.rwrite1.txt to run multi feature regression, but i'm getting an "ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2." . Btw, does the input has to be a float?

```
database = open(r'diabetes.rwrite1.txt','r').readlines()[1:]
lstx = []
lsty = []
for line in database:
    splitted = line.split()
    lstx.append(splitted[0:9])
    lsty.append(float(splitted[10]))


x_ = np.array(lstx)[:, np.newaxis, 1:9]
x = x_.astype(float)
y = np.array(lsty) 
lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(x, y)
```

Comment: Print out the shapes of x and y and compare with the rules of scikit-learn regarding these. (Non-floats will be cast to float if needed and possible). I also recommend using numpy or pandas to do the read-csv part.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to predict a continuous variable then use LinearRegression. If you want to predict categories then you  need to use a classifier such as LogisticRegression or RandomForestClassifier.

In sklearn these nearly always have "classifier" in the name.